# Android how to download something WITHOUT showing any notification or notifying the user

Tags: android, notifications, download-manager

I want to download a file using downloadManager but I don't want to show any notifications. I think the term for this is silent downloading.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

You can use `IntentService` for downloading files without any notification.

You can refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

**Method :2**

Also you can use `BroadCastReceiver` Which is used to capture the Network state changing, Reboot, etc. You can start download from there.

**Method 3:**

Use `AsynkTask` for downloading file at the background

Comment: Should I use downloadManager In the intentService?